# A list of tricks for calculating expectations?

Tags: references, expected-value, moment-generating-function

Does anyone know of a good resource listing known tricks (with examples?) for calculating closed form expressions from messy expectations? (e.g., moment generating function, law of iterated expectations, change of measure, etc.)

In a different setting, I've found [Summary of Rules for Identifying ARIMA Models](http://www.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm) tremendously helpful. I was hoping a list of rules-of-thumb like this would also exist for calculating expectations...right? Unfortunately, I'm not finding anything.

Comment: calculating expectations almost always involves integration. Unfortunately there are no universal simple rules how to calculate integrals.

Comment: @mpiktas I believe anyone who has taught a freshman calculus course might consider disagreeing a little :-).

Comment: @whuber, the key word here is universal. There are simple rules which can help a lot for a large class of integrals. I just wanted to make a point, that there are no similar rules like rules for differentiation. Rereading the question, I see that I missed the point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to simplify an expression involving expectations, Economists’ Mathematical Manual has a nice concise list of identities. You can find a copy online [here](http://www.tbparis.com/Econ230/References%20from%20Web/Sydsaeter%20etal%20-%20Economists%27%20Mathematical%20Manual,%204th%20Edition,%20Springer%20%282005%29.pdf).

Comment: Definitely a nice reference. Didn't find what I was looking for...but I'll hold onto this. I'm sure it'll come in handy at some point :)

Comment: Link is broken (at least when and how I try it).

Answer (score 3):

Let's build it!

You mentioned:

1 moment generating function

2 law of iterated expectations

3 change of measure

Adding:

4 Decompose random variable as a sum. Usually the sum of indicators of something.

5 Build a reccurence relation for E(X) (or a set of linear equations). Useful in Markov Chains.

6 Stopping time theorem for martingales: $E(X_{T})=E(X_{1})$

6b Wald identity. $E(S_{T})=E(X_{1})E(T)$

7 Kolmogorov forward/backward equation

8 [Crofton](http://web.mit.edu/urban_or_book/www/book/chapter3/3.5.html)'s method

9 General idea: Symmetry. Especially for "$n$ points are chosen uniformly on the $[0;1]$" problems.

Comment: Right! This is kind of the idea. Maybe should put up a wiki toward which everyone can contribute. (My next project once I'm done with my dissertation :>) Was never aware of Crofton's method btw. Pretty cool!